# Test Impact Analysis & Ms build execute only Impacted Test

Tags: tfs, msbuild, mstest

I have a TFS build in VS2010. Following the build unit tests are executed. 
In the Build summary it tells me that "1 test run(s) completed - 100% average pass rate" but below this it states "No tests were impacted".

I guess Impacted Tests relate to functionality providing the ability to only run tests that were impacted by code checked in?

Or is there a way that i can run only tests which where impacted based on result of Test Impact Analysis.

I have  Set "Analyze Test Impact" to True but still no result coming and its executing all test cases in test projects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following thing worked for me.

Microsoft.TeamFoundation.TestImpact

http://scrumdod.blogspot.in/2011/03/tfs-2010-build-only-run-impacted-tests.html